# The IMqttClient class does not provide any mean to specify the client ID?

Tags: android, mqtt, messagebroker, paho

This class `IMqttClient()` allows you to create a `client` object with a callback to all possible events to happen, for an example

```
@Override
public void subscribe(String arg0) throws MqttException, MqttSecurityException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void setCallback(MqttCallback arg0) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void publish(String arg0, byte[] arg1, int arg2, boolean arg3) throws MqttException, MqttPersistenceException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

But this class does not allow you to specify an `ID` for each client. How that is possible? especially if you want to connect with `clean session = false`?

Also, i have checked the class `MqttConnectOptions` when you instantiate an object you can set the `server URI` as an option and later you can do something like that `client.connect(opts)`, but there is no way to specify the `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Paho Library provides an option to give the client Id in constructor itself while creating the object of Mqttclient:

Here is the syntax:

```
mClient = new MqttClient(Constant.serverLink, Constant.client_id, null);
```

You can provide the client over there.

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the libraries from com.ibm.mqtt.IMqttClient, you specify the clientId when you connect:

```
mqttClient.connect(clientId, cleanStart, keepAliveSeconds);
```

For more information, please refer to this documentation: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html

If you're using another library, read the documentation. They will definitely allow you to specify a clientId. It would be quite useless not to have one since you wouldn't be able to do anything other than broadcasting without it.